# Tuple returning numeric value if no getter used

Tags: python, tuples

Let me first say I figured out how to fix this, but I'm unsure as to the underlying cause.

I wrote a simple GPS Tagger that uses tkinter to accept various inputs, optionally gets GPS coordinates via pynmea2, and then outputs every filled field to a CSV file. The user can then clear the input fields to move onto the next point.

I realized yesterday while using it that one specific field was frequently incrementing by one, so it made sense for me to include an option to have it auto-increment it. I used tk.Checkbutton to do so.

The field names that are used internally and in the CSV file are stored as a tuple, e.g.

```
fields = 'gs_rated_input_voltage', ... 'gs_equipment_location'
```

Upon being commanded to save the current inputs, a for loop iterates over all filled text boxes, and returns them out of that function. The entries are stored as a list in the function, and as the return type isn't declared to be anything different, I'm assuming the tuple contents are being stored in the list.

When commanded to clear the inputs, if the specific field is filled and the checkbox checked, the value is stored and sliced:

```
text = entry[1].get()
mod_text = str(text)
last_int = int(mod_text[-1:])
mod_text = mod_text[:-1] + str(last_int + 1)
entry[1].delete(0, tk.END)
entry[1].insert(0, mod_text)
```

The entries contain numbers, letters, and hyphens, but the last character is reliably a number - this works, but as an aside if someone has a better way I'm all ears.

All this to say, I found out that if I didn't include the .get() on the first line, text would be set to .58366352.58366416 every time, regardless of whatever was inputted - numbers, letters, a mix, etc.

Can someone explain what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `entry` is a list of `tkinter.Entry` widgets, think about what you are doing when you do the following:

```
text = entry[1]
mod_text = str(text)
```

So `entry[1]` is a widget. When you call `str()` on an object, you request its string representation. There is nothing that would gurantee that you would get the entry’s *content* here.

Instead, what you get back is the *path* to the widget. The path is basically a description where the widget lives within the tkinter frame. It is a combination of all the names in the hiearchy down from the widget’s master, separated by a dot.

So the value `.58366352.58366416` means that the name of the widget itself is `58366416`, and it exists within a different widget with the name `58366352` which has the root (which has no name) as its parent.

But in order to get the actual text from an entry widget, you do have to call [`Entry.get()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.get-method).

Comment: Don't know why I didn't see that initially; I was getting wrapped up in entry[1] being the text contained in the widget, since entry[0] is the label.